# Understanding dual characterization of minimal elements

Tags: convex-optimization

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/):

[image]

where Fig 2.25 is:
[image]

I have two questions (First para makes sense to me):

- Q1: The first line of second para describes what it means for $x$ to be minimal. I am confused what is $K$ here? It seems that for second para we are not referring to the set S (as set S is clearly not convex), but I am confused how K (a cone) is chosen when we talk about a set S?
- Q2: For the second para, how come we can say that: From the first inequality we conclude $\lambda \succeq_{K_*} 0$?